# Why is my global variable `null` inside functions in `web.php` file?

Tags: php, laravel

Coming from the Javascript world, I have read about PHP global variables and how to reference them inside functions using `global` keyword. 
But when i'm trying to `dd($posts)` it returns `null`. Here's the code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

$posts = [
    [
        'image'       => 'https://picsum.photos/id/900/1600/900',
        'title'       => 'Post title',
        'author'      => 'Author',
        'link'        => '#0',
    ],
    [
        'image'       => 'https://picsum.photos/id/900/1600/900',
        'title'       => 'Post title',
        'author'      => 'Author',
        'link'        => '#0',
    ],
];

Route::get('/', function () {
    global $posts;
    dd($posts); // returns null
    return view('pages.home', compact('posts'));
})->name('home');
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for `global` here. Use `use` to inherit a variable from the parent scope:

```php
Route::get('/', function () use ($posts) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `use($posts)`. You can use the below code in your route.

```
Route::get('/', function () use($posts) {
    dd($posts);
    return view('pages.home', compact('posts'));
})->name('home');
```